# Подключить скрипт в WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно нужно подключить свой скрипт в `WordPress` перед встроенным `jQuery` ?

Я делаю таким образом, но ничего не получается. В `functions.php` добавляю код:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script('common', get_template_directory_uri().
    '/js/common.js', array('jquery'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Файл `common.js` :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });

  function windowSize() {
    if ($(window).width() <= '650') {
      $('.top_cont').detach().insertAfter('.nav_menu');
      document.getElementById("name").placeholder = "Ваше имя";
      document.getElementById("phone").placeholder = "Телефон";

    } else {
      $('.nav_menu').detach().insertAfter('.top_cont');
      document.getElementById("name").placeholder = "Введите имя";
      document.getElementById("phone").placeholder = "Введите номер телефона";

    }
    if ($(window).width() <= '650') {
      $('.cen').detach().insertAfter('.prem');
      $('.cen').detach().insertAfter('.usl');
    } else {}
  }
  $(window).load(windowSize);
  $(window).resize(windowSize);
});
```

Comment: в коде визуально ошибок нет. проверьте путь к файлу скрипта. а также убедитесь, что работает сам скрипт, независимо от cms

Answer (score 1):

Во первых посмотрите прописался ли скрипт в хедере, во вторых попробуйте подключить более новую версию jquery

```
function new_jquery() { 
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action('new_v_jquery', 'new_jquery');
```